# Android Emulator INSTRUMENTATION_RESULT: shortMsg=Process crashed

Tags: android, docker, emulation

I am running an android emulator inside a docker container, using '`system-images;android-29;google_apis;x86'` emulator and using the AVD with this options:

```
nohup emulator -avd android-29 -no-boot-anim -no-audio -no-window -no-accel -no-snapshot-load -skin 1440x2560 &
```

The local test in Android studio works fine, but those test inside the docker container are crashing when I am doing the instrumentation test. The following are the final lines in the logcat:

```
[docker] 08-26 03:50:16.714  1934  1945 I system_server: Background young concurrent copying GC freed 135098(7350KB) AllocSpace objects, 32(3080KB) LOS objects, 34% free, 11MB/17MB, paused 217us total 1.330s
[03:50:17] :         [docker] 08-26 03:50:17.051  5666  5718 I CarrierServices: [471] cpr.a: Broadcasting Intent { act=com.google.android.ims.SIM_LOADED (has extras) }
[03:50:17] :         [docker] 08-26 03:50:17.176  5666  5666 W gle.android.im: Long monitor contention with owner AsyncTask #1 (5718) at java.lang.Object java.lang.ThreadLocal.get()(ThreadLocal.java:160) waiters=0 in java.lang.String cpr.c() for 11.842s
[03:50:17] :         [docker] 08-26 03:50:17.224  5666  5666 I CarrierServices: [2] cut.a: KEY_CONFIG_IMS_PACKAGE_OVERRIDE_STRING: com.google.android.ims
[03:50:18] :         [docker] 08-26 03:50:17.762  4250  4266 I m.android.phon: Background concurrent copying GC freed 24547(2349KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 49% free, 2111KB/4222KB, paused 126us total 307.286ms
[03:50:18] :         [docker] 08-26 03:50:18.572  5484  5621 W DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for providerinstaller not found.
[03:50:18] :         [docker] 08-26 03:50:18.573  5484  5621 I DynamiteModule: Considering local module providerinstaller:0 and remote module providerinstaller:0
[03:50:18] :         [docker] 08-26 03:50:18.573  5484  5621 W ProviderInstaller: Failed to load providerinstaller module: No acceptable module found. Local version is 0 and remote version is 0.
[03:50:19] :         [docker] 08-26 03:50:18.719  1934  1950 D ConnectivityService: ConnectivityService NetworkRequestInfo binderDied(NetworkRequest [ TRACK_DEFAULT id=31, [ Capabilities: INTERNET&NOT_RESTRICTED&TRUSTED Uid: 10146] ], android.os.BinderProxy@51eabea)
[03:50:19] :         [docker] 08-26 03:50:18.721  1934  2834 D ConnectivityService: ConnectivityService NetworkRequestInfo binderDied(NetworkRequest [ LISTEN id=32, [ Capabilities: INTERNET&NOT_RESTRICTED&TRUSTED&FOREGROUND Uid: 10146] ], android.os.BinderProxy@76caedb)
[03:50:19] :         [docker] 08-26 03:50:18.722  1934  2834 D ConnectivityService: ConnectivityService NetworkRequestInfo binderDied(NetworkRequest [ LISTEN id=30, [ Capabilities: INTERNET&NOT_RESTRICTED&TRUSTED&NOT_VPN&VALIDATED&FOREGROUND&NOT_SUSPENDED Uid: 10146] ], android.os.BinderProxy@eef5d78)
[03:50:19] :         [docker] 08-26 03:50:18.731  1934  2037 D ConnectivityService: releasing NetworkRequest [ TRACK_DEFAULT id=31, [ Capabilities: INTERNET&NOT_RESTRICTED&TRUSTED Uid: 10146] ] (release request)
[03:50:19] :         [docker] 08-26 03:50:18.773  5870  5870 I cr_ChildProcessService: Destroying ChildProcessService pid=5870
[03:50:19] :         [docker] 08-26 03:50:18.793  1692  1692 I Zygote  : Process 4651 exited due to signal 9 (Killed)
[03:50:19] :         [docker] 08-26 03:50:18.840  1934  3284 W ActivityManager: Crash of app com.natgeomobile.ngmagazine.debug running instrumentation ComponentInfo{com.natgeo.tests/com.natgeo.tests.NatGeoAppAndroidTestRunner}
[03:50:19] :         [docker] 08-26 03:50:18.845  5870  5870 I ProcessService: System.exit called, status: 0
[03:50:19] :         [docker] 08-26 03:50:18.849  5870  5870 I AndroidRuntime: VM exiting with result code 0, cleanup skipped.
[03:50:19] :         [docker] 08-26 03:50:18.880  1934  3284 I ActivityManager: Force stopping com.natgeomobile.ngmagazine.debug appid=10146 user=0: finished inst
[03:50:19] :         [docker] 08-26 03:50:18.882  1934  3284 I ActivityManager: Killing 5870:com.google.android.webview:sandboxed_process0:org.chromium.content.app.SandboxedProcessService0/u0a146i0 (adj 0): isolated not needed
[03:50:19] :         [docker] 08-26 03:50:18.889  1934  1963 I libprocessgroup: Successfully killed process cgroup uid 99000 pid 5870 in 0ms
[03:50:19] :         [docker] 08-26 03:50:18.919  1934  5918 W Binder  : Outgoing transactions from this process must be FLAG_ONEWAY
[03:50:19] :         [docker] 08-26 03:50:18.919  1934  5918 W Binder  : java.lang.Throwable
[03:50:19] :         [docker] 08-26 03:50:18.919  1934  5918 W Binder  :    at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(BinderProxy.java:480)
[03:50:19] :         [docker] 08-26 03:50:18.919  1934  5918 W Binder  :    at android.app.IInstrumentationWatcher$Stub$Proxy.instrumentationFinished(IInstrumentationWatcher.java:205)
[03:50:19] :         [docker] 08-26 03:50:18.919  1934  5918 W Binder  :    at com.android.server.am.InstrumentationReporter$MyThread.run(InstrumentationReporter.java:86)
[03:50:19] :         [docker] INSTRUMENTATION_RESULT: shortMsg=Process crashed.
[03:50:19] :         [docker] INSTRUMENTATION_CODE: 0
```

Anyone have an idea about this error?. Thanks in advance.